# iOS App Submission iTunes Connect - where to find list of disallowed words?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, submission

I was trying to submit an app via iTunes Connect and was given a warning when entering a description for the app.  It said I shouldn't used the word "Punjabi" in my description as it may prevent my app from being approved.

Firstly, I'm not sure why that word would be disallowed.  Any ideas?

Second, where can I find a list of disallowed words and the reasons for such?

Comment: I don't think you'll ever find a list of such words - Apple reviewers do differ from one another upon each submission. I think if you have a good read of the Appstore review guidelines on the link below, and then try to avoid the subject areas it discusses. https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: okay, well, I haven't gotten to that stage yet.  This seemed to have been an automated response that popped up as I was entering the description, so their system must be key-word searching or something.